# How to check POP3 mailbox for new messages via Powershell?

Tags: email, powershell, pop3

Is it possible to check POP3 mailbox for new e-mails via Powershell? And if possible, how can this be achieved?

This [link](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/142300-can-powershell-parse-email.html) provides some information but doesn't suit me. I know about NetCmdlets but would prefer not to use commercial tools. Also I do not want to start `outlook.application`. In fact, my goal is to avoid starting outlook, as long as it possible (for performance reasons)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no native POP3 class in the .NET FRAMEWORK. So you can write one using sockets or you can use an exe client. You can try [GetMail for Windows](http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/getmail.html).

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a TCP connection using **TCPClient**, and next, create a **NetworkStream** object, connected to the **TCPClient** object, to read data from the server?

You'll need `System.Net.Sockets` and `System.Net.IO`.

---

Anyway I would search for a [**C#** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+pop3) and then try to get it to powershell.